# Best way to check balance? msg.sender.balance vs balances[msg.sender]

Tags: solidity, balances, payable

If I want to check if the payer has enough funds, should I use...

```
 msg.sender.balance
```

or

```
balances[msg.sender]
```

?

I also see that people usually check balance in the following way:

```
require((balances[msg.sender] + msg.value) >= balances[msg.sender]);
```

I think I missing something, because for me the most logical way would be this:

```
require(msg.sender.balance >= msg.value );
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I think I'm missing something

You're definitely missing something - those are two different balances:

- `msg.sender.balance` is the ether balance of `msg.sender`
- `balances[msg.sender]` is the token balance of `msg.sender`

The latter is valid (can be compiled) only in a contract which maintains a storage variable:

```
mapping (address => uint) balances
```

Or in a contract which inherits such contract (typically, a token contract).

Comment: Great! So balances[address] is to manage another token balance. It makes completeley sense!

Answer (score 1):

They are two different things.

`msg.sender.balance` is the protocol-level ethereum balance.

`balances[msg.sender` would be an element in an array or mapping that contains data, usually a number for internal accounting purposes.

For example if you have an ATM contract that holds ETH for users a mapping like `mapping(address => uint) balances` can hold balance *information* for all of the depositors while the total ETH on hand would be all be in `address(this).balance`.

The users' money outside of the system would be in `msg.sender.balance` but that would probably not be relevant. It would not be important check that users don't send more money than they have because the protocol handles that.

It would be crucial to check that the user doesn't withdraw money than the contract's internal accounting says they are entitled to because the contract would have more money available than individual users should receive.

Hope it helps.